# When and how is set DS register at program startup (elf / x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to disassemble some classic programs in order to understand how it works. I sometimes see something like that

```
  MOV DWORD PTR ds:0xXXXXXX, YYYYYh
```

where XXXXXX is a 32 bit address and YYYYY is a 32 bits value

But nothing before put a value in ds register. I see a value with debugger but i do not know where she comes from.

What will do this instruction ?

Put YYYYY at ds+0xXXXXXX address ?

Comment: What operating system are you using to start the program?

Comment: elf systems use a flat memory space, you can ignore the `ds` prefix. In most cases it's not even there, it's just a stupid disassembler that shows the default. `ds` has been set up by the OS and it points to segment with base address 0 and size 4GB.

Comment: Linux 32 bits. It is a 32 bit elf executable running on x86

Comment: Jester: Yes but there is a value in my ds register so what will do this value ? On offset ?

Comment: Nothing, as I said, it's set up by the OS to a segment with base address 0. So that zero is added. Only `fs` and `gs` are used specially, if you encounter those, they are not zero based.

Answer (score 5):

As required by the sysv ABI for i386 [(PDF here, see page 3-29)](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf):

> %cs,%ds,%es,%ss
>
> The segment registers are initialized so that the user process can
> address the code, data, and stack segments using a 32-bit virtual
> address.  A program that alters their values does not conform to
> the ABI and has undefined behavior.

The Linux kernel puts a usable value in `%ds` when it starts your program.

Comment: A copy of the current revision of the ABI is hosted on [Intel's open-source site](https://01.org/sites/default/files/file_attach/intel386-psabi-1.0.pdf).  One major change from the old SCO version is requiring 16B stack alignment, and of course defining how xmm and ymm vector args are passed/returned.  The [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has links to the github project and discussion group for the x86 System V ABIs.

Comment: @PeterCordes that version seems to be missing the thing we're looking for (initial state of segment selectors)

Comment: Oh weird, you're right.  Unless search in the pdf is broken, it only mentions them to say that it's unspecified whether data and stack segments are initially mapped with exec permission.  It's probably possible to look at the revision history for the ABI document and find the commit message that went with removing the paragraph you quoted, but I'm not that interested.